# Ubuntu Touch/Phone sim card contacts import

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Im looking for a possibility to import the contacts saved on my sim-card into my bq ubuntu phone, I've no idea how to do it, can u help me pls?

Answer (score 3):

I have not been able to import contacts from my sim-card to the bq ubuntu phone, but you may work around this issue by:

1. synchronizing contacts on your sim-card and android phone with google mail,
2. adding a google account to the bq ubuntu phone through the menu: \system settings\accounts,
3. allowing the account to access the google contacts list and synchronizing with the bq ubuntu phone.

All your contacts are then available in the bq ubuntu phone contacts list

Answer (score 2):

Go to Contacts of your Android Phone and select Import/Export, Export. After this action a *.vcf file will be created and contains all your contacts.

Install Dekko email client on Ubuntu Phone, email the *.vcf file to your account, and open this file in Dekko. Import will start automatically.

Comment: worked for me, not sure, why rating is -1?

Answer (score 0):

to export from android, search the google store for "contact export". this will save your contacts in csv, vcf, pdf to your phone. you then copy from phone to pc via any means you prefer: wifi, blue, usb.