# How to import Contacts form Sim Card to Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My new BQ Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu Edition just arrived, but it seems like it can't find any of my contacts on my sim card. How can i fix that ?

Comment: That workaround works for me: From Dekko http://askubuntu.com/questions/598479/ubuntu-touch-phone-sim-card-contacts-import#new-answer

Answer (score 4):

The feature of SIM contacts import is not on the current stable phone images. However, it is available on the development images. Soon, the development images will be stable enough to ship as an OTA update to all the phone users, and will become the new stable images.

You can choose to wait for the update to come which will include that feature, or you can switch to the development channel to test it.

Comment: So how can I switch to the development channel to test it ?